# Break condition in iteration

Tags: c, for-loop, iteration, break, control-flow

Following is the insertion  sort code i wrote

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int i, j, a[10], temp, f = 0, k = 0;
    clrscr();
    printf("\n\t\t\t\tINSERTION SORT\nEnter the Array:-\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)                  // 1st for loop
    {
        temp = a[i];
        for (j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++)               // 2nd  for loop
        {
            f = 0;
            if (a[i]<a[j])                      //  if loop
            {
                for (k = i - 1; k >= j; k--)            //   3rd for loop
                    a[k + 1] = a[k];
                a[k + 1] = temp;
                break;                              // break statement
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe sorted array is:-\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    getch();
}
```

I was told that break statement  stops that particular instant(***nth*** time of currently running innermost loop & initiates its next instance ( *n+1* time). So here I am confused that whether the break  statement here will stop the 3rd loop or if condition. I was however told that it will affect the second loop.

Can anyone here please tell me on which for loop it is going to have its effect.

Comment: What you were told suits the `continue` statement. Also *"if loop"* is not a thing.

Comment: Ewww `conio`...

Comment: First of all [**format**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_c_formatter.htm) that mess. It's completely unreadable.

Comment: What you were told suits the `continue` statement. The `break` statement just exits the loop (the 2nd  for loop in your case)
.

Answer (score 4):

The `break` will *stop the loop*, not the if statement.

So here:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)                 // 1st for loop
{
    temp = a[i];
    for (j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++)         // 2nd  for loop
    {
        f = 0;
        if (a[i]<a[j])                   //  if STATEMENT
        {
            for (k = i - 1; k >= j; k--) //   3rd for loop
                a[k + 1] = a[k];
            a[k + 1] = temp;
            break;                      // break statement
        }
    }
}
```

, assuming that `i` has the value 0, when the `break` gets executed, it will *prevent* the 2nd loop from executing again, and you will exit that loop. As a result, you will go again at the 1st loop, where a new iteration will start, with `i` equal to 1.

What you describe suggests the `continue` keyword, which again has to do with loops only, it's not something that affects an if statement directly.

In the code above, if a `continue` statement was used instead of a `break` one, then you would *skip* that iteration (meaning that nothing below `continue` would be executed), and move on with the next iteration of the 2nd loop (giving `j` its incremented by one value). However, in your code, there is nothing bellow that line, so it wouldn't make any difference.

---

PS:

This comment is wrong:

```
if (a[i]<a[j])  //  if loop  <-- WRONG
```

An if statement is not a loop.

Comment: actually I dont understand where the reference to `continue` is coming from (i mean I see the comment, but I dont understand it).

Comment: @tobi303 from the code structure of OP's code. This would leave the block of the `if` because there's no other statement in the surrounding `for` block after the `if` block.

Comment: Hmm @tobi303 might have a point here. It might confuse the OP, should I remove the `continue` part from my answer?

Comment: I would at least explain what continue does, because in general it does not "break" out of an if block.

Comment: Yes, but I think with the explanation now added, it shouldn't be confusing (and actually gives some added value over the dupe I found ;))